# Move characters using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to move the colors and size beside of "Color and Size" using regex? This is my regex: https://regex101.com/r/fB3jK9/1

The result should be like this:

My sample input is:

```
Color and Size - Dark Blue|Small
    Dark Blue|Medium
    Dark Blue|Large
    Dark Blue|X-Large
Color and Size - Black|Small
    Black|Medium
    Black|Large
    Black|X-Large
    Ocean|Small
    Ocean|Medium
    Ocean|Large
    Ocean|X-Large
Color and Size - Black|Small
    Black|Medium
    Black|Large
    Black|X-Large
    Black|2X-Large
    Stone|Small
    Stone|Medium
    Stone|Large
    Stone|X-Large
    Stone|2X-Large
```

So far all I've been able to come up with to use is:

```
\n\t
```

But I need the output of:

```
Color and Size - Dark Blue|Small, Dark Blue|Medium, Dark Blue|Large, Dark Blue|X-Large



Color and Size - Black|Small, Black|Medium, Black|Large, Black|X-Large, Ocean|Small, Ocean|Medium, Ocean|Large, Ocean|X-Large






Color and Size - Black|Small, Black|Medium, Black|Large, Black|X-Large, Black|2X-Large, Stone|Small, Stone|Medium, Stone|Large, Stone|X-Large, Stone|2X-Large








// end output
```

Comment: yes so where's the question ?

Comment: You shouldn't do this via regex, but it's probably possible to HARDCODE it to work right. I'll write up a solution in python.

Comment: @AdamSmith, Im using jquery, hope you can help me

Comment: @NewtoJava if you're using jQuery, that means you have access to Javascript. I haven't used js in about a decade, so I *can't*, but I'll retag your question as such. Edit your question so it's obvious

Comment: For completeness sake, edit your question and add 1) the input string 2) the regex you used and 3) the current output you get.

Comment: what is your finding or effort so far?

Comment: Your regex looks like its doing the job.  Do you just need the extra blank lines?

Comment: @Schwern i want the size and colors move beside of ""Color and Size" and the newlines will not be deleted.

Comment: @NewtoJquery [The regex you linked to](https://regex101.com/r/fB3jK9/1) alters the string to match your desired output.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest getting the 'blocks' together and the running the replacement inside a function, for example like this:

```
// Getting a block
var regex = /Color and Size[\s\S]*?(?=Color and Size|$)/gi;

// Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/q/29339480/1578604 to repeat string
String.prototype.repeat = function( num ) {
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}

var results = text.replace(regex, function(m) {
    // Get number of line breaks
    var lb = m.split("\n").length - 1;
    // Now remove newlines and tabs, then add the linebreaks at the end
    return m.replace(/\n\t/g, ", ") + "\n".repeat(lb);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqg2e3e1/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Jerry can you convert into jquery?

Comment: @NewtoJquery Sorry, I don't know JQuery at all :( From my understanding though, there shouldn't be anything to convert as there's just a string, a function and a replace. You should be able to insert it among your code I think.